# How to add git hash to my project on build - Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I would like to access some information about my project for testing purposes. For example, I'd like to append the git hash or and installed module version as a param on one of my requests. What I came up with (which works) is to include a prebuild script in my `package.json`

```
"prebuild": "node scripts/prebuild.js"
```

and in that script

```
var fs = require('fs');
var child_process = require('child_process');

const revision = child_process
  .execSync('git rev-parse HEAD')
  .toString().trim()

const module_version = child_process
  .execSync('npm view module version')
  .toString().trim()

const params = `module.exports = {
  git_hash: '${revision}',
  module_version: '${module_version}'
};`

fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/../src/helpers/params.js', params, () => {
  console.log('Prebuild finished');
});
```

and then import that file where needed

```
import params from './src/helpers/params';
```

However this seems kinda hacky to me and I wonder if there's a way to utilize webpack to help me achieve this in a better/safer way.

Comment: How are you wanting Webpack to utilize this?

Comment: @Adam That's sort of what I'm asking. I'm trying to determine if there is a standard way to get the same results (git hash / module info available in my application build). It doesn't necessarily need to involve Webpack. I'm open to other solutions. That's just the first place my mind went as a possibility.

Comment: Since you already have the script written, I can't think of a way Webpack could improve on this since it could only do exactly what you're already doing. It could possibly provide the hash and module version as globals for use anywhere in your app if you made your own integration for it.

Comment: There is no other way to do that with or without webpack. The way you are doing is the way to go.